# USB LPT Converter by FT232R

Tags: microcontroller, usb

I am really green and even greener in these topics, but i am trying to create a project which will be converting lpt signal to usb signal via FT232RL. I was searching a lot in internet and i have some question about that

FT232RL differs from FT232R?

[image: USB connected to FT232RL]

Clearly the usb communication is pretty easy because there is a plenty of projects about that and plenty of information in data sheet( usbdm usbdp pins). But what can i do to communicate with LPT by remaining slots? I do not know how to find proper informations. Will it work when i connect LPT port to proper pins?

I know that question may be really dumb, but i am really confused about that.

Comment: Pretty sure you have the wrong chip for the task. [Parallel port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port)  versus [RS232.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port)  Your FT232 is intended to connect to RS232 over USB.  Will **not** do you any good for a parallel (LPT) connection.

Comment: My main goal is to do "LPT to USB converter"  and i have to do USB communication via FT232RL, so i should use something else than FT232RL, with that device i cant do proper parallel connection?

Comment: You **can't** do parallel (LPT) to USB with just the FT232.  If you get creative, you might be able to use a serial to parallel shift register at the output and so drive the output, or use a parallel to serial shift register and read the inputs.  Both will require extra software on the PC, and it will **not** "look" like a parallel port to your operating system.

Comment: Just **buy** a parallel port to USB converter, and use the software that comes with it.

Comment: You say you "have to" use the FT232RL. Is this some sort of assignment? If so, they may intend for you to communicate using the FT232RL with a microcontroller's UART, and then use that microcontroller to generate the relevant parallel-port signals to send to a printer.

Comment: So by that UART i can in some kind convert connected data to data actually i need? But still i have to connect LPT to FT232RL right? And then i can try to convert this by software?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the [datasheet](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf) explains it just fine:

[image]

The L just indicates that it's in a 28-pin SSOP package, as opposed to the 32-pin QFN used by the Q variant.

As for the second question... Isn't the LPT (printer port, parallel port) signal format inherently different from the COM (serial port) format that the FT232 is meant to interpret? I think you may have the wrong chip for the job.

Comment: My main goal is to do "LPT to USB converter"  and i have to do USB communication via FT232RL, so i should use something else than FT232RL, with that device i cant do proper parallel connection? Or i just misunderstood something?

Comment: @endrew I don't know enough about the various forms of communication in computers to say, I'm afraid.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted please let me know why? I can't exactly improve the answer (or future answers) without knowing what's wrong with it.

Comment: It was not me, on this forum i do not even have ability to vote without 15 rep :(, but i do not know as well why someone downvoted you...

Comment: @endrew That's fine! I'm not blaming you or anything. I just want to know what I did wrong so that I can do better in future.

Comment: +1 for answering 1st point.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from you question the intent of your device. It depends what you are trying to do.

If you are trying to make a USB --> LPT output port, then you may have the wrong chip, and you more likely need a USB-->FIFO parallel port. Try the FTDI240X or FT122 for the task.
Even then you need a driver on the USB side and logic/MCU to create the LPT signals.
You will find it extremely challenging to emulate the LPT ports in a PC over USB since the only way to do this is to use virtual registers, which implies complexity.

Creating an LPT output port (the 25pin connector) is cheaply achieved by buying a USB-Parallel adapter such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000UX21PY) ….why would you struggle to develop this?

However, if what you are really trying to do is receive data from an LPT port output (on a PC for example) and lift this data into another device then you are looking to emulate a **printer** not a printer port. There are solution for this too, an example [here](http://www.pclviewer.com/resources/capture/hardware.html).

More clarity on exactly what your intent is, may allow provision of more help.

Comment: I have to design a LPT (IEEE1284) to USB converter , that converter should use EPP mode and should allow to drive all the data and commands lines of the LPT port. The device shold be controlled via USB. So i assume my research was pretty bad, so any tips how can i start to cope with that

Comment: IEEE1284 was developed in the 1970s by Centronics. This is old news easily found by ordinary web search methods with the right key words.